# html form load from db, but leave first option empty

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I have a form in which i choose data from database. I would like the first option to be blank ( I created an "empty" database row, but how is the correct way to do it?

```
<select id="spolecnost" name="spolecnost">
<?php
$result=mysqli_query($connection, "select * from spolecnosti order by nazev;");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<option><?php echo $row["nazev"]; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 1):

Output a blank option row before you loop through the results of the query.

```
<select id="spolecnost" name="spolecnost">
<option>-- Select an option --</option>
<?php
$result=mysqli_query($connection, "select * from spolecnosti order by nazev;");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<option><?php echo $row["nazev"]; ?></option>
```

You may put anything you'd like in place of

> -- Select an option --

of course.